# configure properties of LocalSessionFactoryBean in grails

Tags: hibernate, spring, grails

I have grails project using my **existing Java domain classes** of a **spring project** and I need to configure **typeDefinitions**. In the spring project it is possible to configure this property of the **LocalSessionFactoryBean** - but how do you do that in a grails project?

Answer (score 2):

The Grails version of LocalSessionFactoryBean is a subclass, org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean. It's registered as a Spring bean in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.orm.hibernate.HibernatePluginSupport as

```
sessionFactory(ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean) {
   ...
}
```

so you have a couple of options. One is to redefine the bean in resources.groovy, maintaining what Grails configures plus your changes, i.e.

```
sessionFactory(MyCustomConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean) {
   ...
   typeDefinitions = ...
}
```

or if possible you can reference the bean and modify it in BootStrap:

```
class BootStrap {

   def sessionFactory

   def init = { servletContext ->
      sessionFactory.foo = bar
   }

   def destroy = {}
}
```

It looks like typeDefinitions need to be configured early, while the factory bean is building the SessionFactory, so option 1 is probably your best bet.

Comment: this seems like the right way to achieve what I want but I have to admit that my grails knowledge is not as good as my spring knowledge - so could you please give me a tip on how to "redefine the bean in resources.groovy, maintaining what Grails configures plus your changes"?

Answer (score 1):

another option is to use spring's life-cycle callbacks, e.g. implementing a BeanPostProcessor

```
public class CustomBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

// simply return the instantiated bean as-is
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    return bean; // we could potentially return any object reference here...
}

public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    if ("sessionFactory".equals(beanName) && bean instanceof ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean)  {
        ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = (ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean) bean;
        sessionFactory.setTypeDefinitions(...);
    }
    return bean;
}
```

}

and throw it to your resources.groovy

```
customProcessor(CustomBeanPostProcessor)
```

this way you don't have to redefine the sessionFactory bean thats already wired into GORM dynamic finders et.al.

Comment: nice suggestion, the problem is that postProcessAfterInitialization is never called for a bean named sessionFactory or an instance of ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean :-(

Comment: did you add the bean definition to your resources.groovy? i've tested the code above and setting TypeDefinitions did work that way.

Comment: I found out why this does not work for my situation: sessionFactory can't be instantiated because it fails when loading the mapping information - because it does not know the configured UserType.

So I need to configure these TypeDefinitions before the sessionFactory is instantiated

Comment: why don't you specify the type-definitions through Hibernate's <typedef> element or annotation?